# advice on response web design

Tags: asp.net, html, css, responsive-design

i manage an ecommerce website for a client (website is very similar to newegg.com) high bandwidth lots of pages & info.

we build the website in 2010 based on asp.net 2.0

now we need to redesign the website to make it responsive. i  need an advice what platform should we look at, which works well & easy to use. i have no experience in responsive design currently but i can learn or outsource the work.

i have read on bootstrap, is this the best option available currently ?

please guide me.

Comment: You are not up to the task if you have to come here and ask a question like this.  You should outsource the work to someone who knows how to do it.  If you're written the app correctly it should be a UI change.  The REST services in the back won't need to change.

Comment: this is primarily opinion based question and because of that it's off topic

Comment: The best option is: write it yourself. If this needs to much time use bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is very simple to make the best websites responsive and make very simple to learn.

You can manipulate wherever you want.

[http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/%C2%B4)

Next you can use the JQUERY and AJAX in this for develop a website more interative.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Comment: thanks for all the answer ... so bootstrap is way forward. 

i will most probably outsource the work ..

Comment: First of all you have to know what is your users needs and next you have to use a great UI and UX to make the most website engage users.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [duffymo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/37213/duffymo) in that you should be very careful in what work you take on. If you're asking this question you likely have quite a lot of research to do.

That being said, in addition to bootstrap (as Paulo mentioned) I enjoy using Google's [Material Design Lite](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html) library. Their grid is as easy to use as Bootstrap's and it gives you the currently-popular material design feel.

If you'd rather not use something so heavy then give [flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) a shot. They're native to css3 but may have issues if you have to support a lot of older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the guides for Usuability here

http://scholar.google.pt/scholar_url?url=http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm%3Fid%3D519216&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&scisig=AAGBfm0tKXSqNq1HaFFnjJXUvPsdQ8pxTA&nossl=1&oi=scholarr&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiUzobhtq3OAhUJRhQKHR2oDY8QgAMIGigAMAA

And use the Balsamick to create a prototype for your website/application